# need to lazy load ES6 module with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

require('./gulp/index');
```

index.js

```
global.gulp = require('gulp');
global.path = require('path');
global.plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

require('./config');

var bulk = require('bulk-require');
bulk(__dirname, ['./tasks/*']);

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'js', 'jscontroller']);
```

config.js

```
global.config = {};
config.PROJECT_ROOT = path.join(__dirname, '..');
config.DIST = path.join(config.PROJECT_ROOT, 'public/dist');

config.clean = {
src: config.PROJECT_ROOT + '/public/dist/**/*'
};

config.js = {
src: [config.PROJECT_ROOT + '/app/assets/javascripts/modules/**/*.js'],
dest: config.DIST,
webpackOptions: require(config.PROJECT_ROOT + '/webpack.config.js')
};
config.jscontroller = {
src: [config.PROJECT_ROOT + '/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/**/*.js'],
dest: config.DIST,
webpackOptions: require(config.PROJECT_ROOT + '/webpack.config.js')
};

config.watch = {
js: {
task: 'js',
src: config.PROJECT_ROOT + '/app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js'
}
};

module.exports = config;
```

Using gulp + webpack to browserify(+babel)

I would like to lazy load 'Page Controllers' on demand. But currently I get one massively compiled main.js file. I'm trying to keep the files seperate. Is there a way to do this. Im trying to use ES6 in these modules so I'll need to obviously run them through babel but then what is the right way to load them with webpack as seperate files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do lazy-loading with Webpack by working out my imports inside event listeners, and using this specific syntax here:

```
document.getElementById('loadCat').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    require.ensure([], () => {
        var Cat = require('./cat').Cat;

        var myCat = new Cat('Bugsy');
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += `<br/>${myCat.meow()}`;
    });
```

});

From my experience, Webpack is smart enough to not include anything from `require.ensure` in the main bundle, but instead in a separate bundle.

This is working fine for me, I have open-sourced this example here: [gulp-es6-webpack-example](https://github.com/tiagorg/gulp-es6-webpack-example)